# unknow bug:body have different margin on some pages

Tags: wordpress

Im working on wordpress site [see LINK](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk)I have huge trouble, I dont know what to do, I dont see what  is the problem, I staring in code and dont see.

Just look on home page [home page](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk)
and this page [second page](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk/dining-at-redcoats/)

whats make this margin from top browser chrome to white border of the header on second page.That margin is not showing on home page.Similiar situation on other pages.

pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using firebug inspect, i see that the second page have alot of header tags in the BODY section, insted of having them in the HEAD section, that why the browser adding the padding between the "junk" and the #outer-div.

I can't relly see the diference in the code, but i can see that its breakes almost directly after:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

as your doctype saing you using XHTML, you should rewrite that row as XHTML,
by adding the / at the end, so that tag gets properly closed.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

if that still dosn't fix the problem, try using http://validator.w3.org/check until your code is XHTML, then all browser should display it as XHTML, the case at the moment look like the browser accpets the code as bad written XHTML on some pages, and on other its thinks its bad labeled HTML 4, and therefor render the page as HTML 4

Comment: closing tag didnt solve the issue.I try to validate page, but i get following:Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 163 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
The error was: utf8 "\xC0" does not map to Unicode

Comment: on that line(163) is some js code made by dotmailer widget.I think that is maybe following line in js the problem:var reg = /^[�-��-�A-Za-z0-9.+_'%\-&]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[0-9A-Za-z-]{2,}$/;

what do you think?

Comment: No, thats not the problem.When I turn of that plugin, bug is still here.Oh, my...

Comment: if you tell w3 that its a "iso-8859-1", its going to show you the rest of the other errors insted, and you can try to fix the encoding error later

Comment: sorry for miss leading you, i looked a bit closer and notice the BOM on your second page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: What does this mean?Sorry, but I read wiki, and not sure what to do?